# Coinbase ghost transactions - what happened?

Tags: wallets, etherscan, coinbase, hack

I went through the following process with a new wallet, and I lost my funds (not a lot)...

I am trying to understand, from the blockchain perspective, what actually happened.

This is the wallet in question: https://etherscan.io/address/0x370249a89bbC8A4B9B40743d73158a35B5C2980D

1. I transferred 0.027 ETH from Coinbase to Coinbase Wallet (new wallet)
2. I bought an NFT on OpenSea.
3. 9 hours later, my wallet was cleared out to zero.

There are only 3 transactions.  how did the hacker gain access to my account?

I found there were also two transactions on polygon:

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x370249a89bbC8A4B9B40743d73158a35B5C2980D#tokentxnsErc721